# Find digit 1 in 50,000

Tags: number-theory

The following is the problem I have been working on. After spending considerable amount of time to list 1s, I got the result but it is wrong. There must be an easy way to solve the problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

> How many times does the digit $1$ appear in the numbers $1$ through $50,000$?

Comment: zero times? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @CarryonSmiling hmm.... but are you sure XD The 1 might just be really hidden

Comment: How is this related to prime numbers? I suggest combinatorics

Comment: @NoahHarris The initial question was not very well written. It is revised.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling The question is revised by Shai and is more precise now.

Answer (score 2):

Well lets find out, 1-9 contains. 1, 10, contains 1 so 2 so far, 11-20 has 9 so 11 so far. 20-30 has 1, so 12 so far 30-99 has 6 so 18, so far 100 contains, 1, we already calculated the values for 1-99 which equals 18. then we note for 100-199 each number contains a 1 so we have 18 +100 ones this section and 18+100+18 so far. 200-299 well thats just 1-99 which is 18, 300-999 well thats just 1-99 eight times so we have (18)+(100+18)+9*(18) 1s for 1-999 Continue on in this pattern until 50,000.

Comment: It is easier to count the number of times $1$ appears in each digit place.

Comment: @rossmollikan that's an excellent point but I find it harder to explain yet easier to calculate.

Comment: In each place except the ten thousands, we have one in ten of the digits a $1$, so each place contributes $5,000\ 1$'s.  The ten thousands place contributes $10,000\ 1$'s